# What is the relation between power and photocurrent?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, frequency, power

Question: A clean lithium surface is illuminated by 1.0 mW of light of wavelength 400 nm. The ejected photoelectrons, which have a maximum kinetic energy of 0.70eV, produce a photocurrent of 30 µA. Calculate the work function of lithium, the threshold frequency and the fraction of photons that liberate electrons.

I have calculated the work function and the threshold frequency and I haven't used the power or photocurrent values yet, which is for finding the fraction of photons.

Answer (score 3):

I would solve this in following way:

1) Compute the number of photons arriving at the surface per second by $$\dot{n}_{photons}=\frac{P_{optical}}{E_{photon}}$$

2) The number of electrons coming out per second is essentially the electric current $I$ divided by the elementary charge $q$.

3) The ratio of those two numbers $$\frac{I/q}{\dot{n}_{photons}}$$ is what we are looking for.